# Where do you put your optical disc drive?

Tags: computer-building, optical-drive, chassis

My case has three places the OD drive could go, where do you prefer your drive?

Currently my drive is in the bottom slot because that is all the longer my SATA cable allows for, but I was just curious as to where people put theirs and do the other slots hold any advantages?

Comment: It does not matter.  Even if it did it would depend on the case.

Comment: Back in the Desktop-chassis days (monitor on top) we used to put them in the upper bay so they would eject over the user's keyboard, instead of bumping into it. :)  As @Ramhound suggests, it doesn't matter, unless the chassis and/or location warrant something specific.

Answer (score 1):

As Ramhound and Techie007 said in the comments, it really doesnt matter where you put it... with a few exceptions.

With any device you attach to your computer, internally or externally, just make sure it doesnt impede the operation or placement of other devices.  Problems that could occur is stretching cables or putting pressure on an internal card.

There are other things to consider, such as airflow and heat.  Some cases are designed to allow air to flow along a certain path.  Generally, they take new drives into account, but it cant hurt to check.

Another factor is sound.  Depending on how the case is made, putting the drive in one bay over another might make it vibrate more and sound louder.

Answer (score 0):

Again, @keltari raises some good points, but i want to bring up one more.

Consider the location of your computer, some people place their computer below the top of their desk, which would put the Tower at "leg level", which would be wise to place the optical drive at the very top of the Tower. Making it easier for you not having to bend all the way down to place the disk or retrieve the disk.

If you place your PC/Tower on top of the desk, you would want to place the optical drive on the very bottom of the PC's slots to be able to reach the drive easier when ejected.